LaTeX need to run 3 times to have the correct table layout
I'm trying to generate a report with xelatex containing a longtable. Somehow, I have to rerun xelatex 3 times to get the table layout right.
Apparently, the problem comes from the last 3 columns and the fact that I use a multicolumn there. Can I somehow avoid generating 3 times?
...

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\footnotesize



\begin{longtable}{
  |
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}|   
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}|   
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}|   
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.8cm}|   
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.2cm}|   
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.8cm}|  
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2cm}|     
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}|   
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.6cm}| 
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.6cm}| 
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{0.6cm}
  }

    % -------------------------- Table Header ---------------------------------

    
    \rowcolor{strapagBlue} 
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Nom du site}} & \textbf{Cell-ID} &\textbf{Pays} & \textbf{Responsable}   & \textbf{BTS-Type} & \textbf{TX-Puissance} & \textbf{Antenne} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Azimut}} \\

    \rowcolor{strapagBlue} 
    \textbf{Code} & \textbf{Cellule} & &\textbf{Canton}  & & \textbf{Status} & \textbf{ERP} & \textbf{Fabricant} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{El. Tilt}} \\

    \rowcolor{strapagBlue} 
    \textbf{X-Coord.} & \textbf{Y-Coord.} & \textbf{Altitude} & \textbf{Commune} & \textbf{Coordination}   & \textbf{Polarisation} & \textbf{Nb. TRX} & \textbf{Haut. Ant.} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Tilt Mech.}} \\

    \hline


    \endhead

    % ---------------- Content ---------------
    
    \rowcolor{lightGray} 
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{XXXXX} } & \textbf{236 0321} & CH & XXXX& Normal BTS, MBSe3 & 38.0dBm & 3 x K741515   
    & 20° &  115°  &  210°  \\ 
    
    \hline

...




It would be great if you could provide a minimal working example, but otherwise, no, it's not really possible if you use \multicolumn. You can see it if you look at the 9 pages long longtable's documentation.
